# how to stop service in ios app when mobile in lock?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I need help from us, and problem is when i calling the service in my ios app ,at this time mobile is locked, and then after unlocked the mobile it's freeze untill service done.so i want open immediately my app without freeze.

Comment: You can't detect the lock of the phone, but you can detect the `applicationWillResignActive:` call on your appdelegate.

Comment: if services means..apis,  then call them at background thread.

Comment: @Larme thanks ...i will try